# UiTableView appearing in wrong place on ViewController ios

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, storyboard

Im currently working on an app that when a button is pressed, it presents a view controller modally over the one the button is on. This works fine and appears in the correct place, however, the modal view controller contains a UiTableView and this seems to appear in the top left of the view controller, no where near where I placed it in storyboards. I have tried adding all the constraints as the image shows below but with no luck. When I add the constraints, the tableview doesn't appear at all.

[image: This is the image showing my Modal View Controller, With the table view being inside a view on the right hand side]

[image: Image showing where the UiTableView appears in relation to the location in storyboards]

[image: Constraints Added]

[image: Result After Constraint]

Hopefully Someone can help as I have hit a dead end.

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you made your UI using storyboards. That's alright, but you should be aware that there is another way to create your UI elements (tableViews, buttons, etc.): programmatically.

Because you used storyboards, you may have forgotten to check/uncheck some setting in it that may cause the problem you are experiencing, and I probably won't be able to diagnose your problem easily. So I will show you how to fix this programmatically.

**Programmatically**

You can set the constraints of your tableView programmatically, within the viewController that you are trying to present.

So if your viewController to be presented is called `viewController` and your tableView is `tableView`, you should have the following:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        /* First, tell XCode that you want to manually set the tableView's constraints using AutoLayout */

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(tableView)

        /* setup constraints for your tableView */
        tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Another (much easier) way to create a viewController that contains a tableView is to simply have the viewController **inherit** from `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. This is a neat little inheritance trick that you can use to make your code much more concise and avoid writing code that does not need to be written. If you inherit from `UITableViewController`, you automatically get a "free" tableView inside you viewController without needing to create a new one:

```
class viewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Usually, we have a viewController inherit from `UITableViewController` if we are only planning to have a single UI element inside it: a tableView. On the other hand, if we want to have a more intricate layout in our viewController (such as a tableView taking only a section of the viewController and the rest of the space being taken up by other UI elements), then we might want to have the viewController inherit from `UIViewController` and then create a tableView inside it (like in the first example I showed you).

**Storyboard**

When using storyboards, the first thing you should make sure that you are doing right is that you are using AutoLayout to set your constraints for your tableView. In *main.storyboard*, go to the view you want to present and click on the tableView. Then, hover your mouse over the "Align" button, right here:

[image]

Make sure that you check both "Horizontally in Container" and "Vertically in Container". This centers your tableView within its superView.

Then, also modify the following:

[image]

Make sure that the "Constraint to margins" option is checked. This constraints the margins of your tableView to its superView (ideally).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. If possible I would prefer to stick to storyboards as the rest of my app is done this way. Strangely I have exactly the same setup with another view but it contains a picker modal but this one works absolutely fine and there are no constraints at all??

Comment: I totally understand that and value what you have said. This is my first app so for now just want to stick to the storyboards. Do you have any idea what I would need to use in storyboards or do you not use them at all?

Comment: yeah no worries at all! Its a great and detailed answer

Comment: that doesn't change anything. The tableview is still appearing in the top left

Comment: Thanks for the help again but that doesn't seem to work either. Two things occur when i start to change constraints, either the tableview appears in the top left or the tableview doesn't appear at all

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help. I have sorted it by getting rid of the view which contains the Label, tableview and buttons and have put all the elements directly on the main view.